# Add Form with OneToMany mapping - cannot add assosiacion between entities

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, thymeleaf

```
Hi, I am trying to create add form where I can create and add to the db new object - Client. The Client entity is associated with another entity - email. I would like to create 2 object in this form - new Client and new Email and create association between them (OneToMany and ManyToOne). Unfortunately, I can only create one object
```

This is my Client class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Client")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Address")
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    private List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is email:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Email") 
public class Email {      

@Id     
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)     
private Integer id;      

@Column(name = "Address")    
 private String address;      

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)     
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")     
private Client client;  
}
```

I preprared the form in thymeleaf like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Create Client</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add client</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/clients/save}"
      th:object="${client}" method="POST">

  <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"
         placeholder="Name">

  <input type="text" th:field="*{address}"
         placeholder="Adress">


  <input type="text" th:field="*{emails[0].address}"
         placeholder="Email">

  <br>
  <button type="submit" >Save</button>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to add to db new Client, together with new Object Email that should be associated with Client by using Jpa Repository, but by now I am able only to create just new Client object. What should I do to properly add new object with associations between them using JPA, Hibernate and Thymeleaf?

Comment: Please add the mapping responsible for handling the post method on '/clients/save'.